# Python create project structure and import packages

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7

I am novice to Python. I need to create project structure where I need to call the packages files inside my TestProj directory's main.py file. Could you please let me know how to call the functions f1() and f2() inside main.py?

```
/scratch/testuser/ProjectDir
            |
            |- TestProjDir
                |- main.py  
    (call f1() from mod_script1.py & f2() from mod_script2.py) here..
            |
            |- PKG_MODULES_Dir
                |- __init__.py
                |- mod_script1.py
                    def f1():
                         print("This is my f1 func from script1")
                |- mod_script2.py
                    def f2():
                         print("This is my f2 func from script2")
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to import modules first like below in your main.py file:

from PKG_MODULES_Dir.mod_script1 import *
from PKG_MODULES_Dir.mod_script2 import *

then you can use directly call f1() and f2() functions in your main.py file

Comment: I tried that already. Actually my main.py script is under /TestProjDir dir.  So I get 'ImportError: No module named' err msg.

Comment: ```
python main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from PKG_MODULES_Dir.mod_script1 import *
ImportError: No module named PKG_MODULES_Dir.mod_script1
```

Comment: try from ProjectDir.PKG_MODULES_Dir.mod_script1 import *

Comment: Yes, tried that as well. Got same error
` python main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ProjectDir.PKG_MODULES_Dir.mod_script1 import *
ImportError: No module named ProjectDir.PKG_MODULES_Dir.mod_script1`